# (Python) Estou com problema de travamento em função específica

Tags: python

Essa função é responsável por armazenar a informação que o usuário digitar em uma caixa de texto específica, são duas, uma para pegar os códigos e a outras as datas desses códigos, formando pares cada um. Porém o usuário tem a liberdade de escolher quantos códigos e datas ele irá preencher, nisso tem uma parte da minha interface onde ele pode digitar a quantidade de vezes necessárias para suprir a necessidade do usuário, ou seja, daí entra a estrutura do looping, que verás logo abaixo, só que o problema aparenta ser o `self.text_edit_2.clear()` e o `self.text_edit_3.clear()`, quando executo o código nessa estrutura (logo abaixo), ele abre a interface normalmente, porém quando eu digitei a quantidade que eu quis pra fazer o teste e fui preencher os códigos e datas, e logo em seguinda eu clico no botão que chama a função, a interface trava e nunca mais volta, nisso só me resta fechar e eu fiz o mesmo teste várias e várias vezes, mas ele continuando dando esse travamento e não volta mais, porém quando eu removo o `self.text_edit_2.clear()` e o `self.text_edit_3.clear()` ele armazena os códigos e datas e cria a tabela, mas o problema é que a tabela é preenchida em todas as linhas e colunas com a mesma informação, por exemplo: na coluna "códigos" o único e primeiro código que o usuário digita vai para todas as linhas dessa coluna o mesmo acontece na coluna "datas", porém só com os números das datas, cada coluna recebe seu respectivo índice, mas esses índices se repetem entre as linhas, que são definidas inicialmente pelo usuário lá, aqui um exemplo:

```
   Códigos    Datas
0    11111  1012024
1    11111  1012024
2    11111  1012024
3    11111  1012024
4    11111  1012024
```

Veja que eu fiz um teste definindo 5 linhas (começando no índice 0), e veja como a tabela ficou, isso porque removi o `self.text_edit_2.clear()` e o `self.text_edit_3.clear()`, ambos são caixa de texto, onde o `self.text_edit_2` é responsável pela entrada dos códigos e o `self.text_edit_3` é responsável pela entrada das datas, só que o grande problema, é que eu não estou conseguindo resolver o que estou tentando chegar, que é simplesmente o usuario digitar o número de códigos e datas que ele vai precisar, que também essa quantidade representa as linhas das colunas, aqui é onde ele define a quantidade dos códigos e datas:

`self.num_linhas = int(self.text_edit.text().strip())`, onde já da pra presumir que self.text_edit é outra caixa de texto, porém só pega a quantidade inserida pelo usuário, tal qual eu fiz ali no teste da tabela acima que foram 5 códigos, logo também representam 5 linhas em cada coluna, é isso, espero que tenham entendido o que estou tentando fazer, já estou nesse problema há 5 dias e não consigo pensar numa solução, agora aparenta ser tão bobo, aliás sou iniciante na programação, principalmente em Python, então relevem erros de sintáxe e essas coisas mais, obrigado até então! Se precisar do código completo, me diga por onde posso passar.

Função que estou enfrentando o problema:

```
#Python
def registrar_dados(self):

        self.dados = {"Códigos": [], "Datas": []}

        self.num_linhas = int(self.text_edit.text().strip())

        linhas_adicionadas = 0

        while linhas_adicionadas < self.num_linhas:

            codigo_item = self.text_edit_2.text()
            data_item = self.text_edit_3.text()

            if codigo_item.strip() and data_item.strip():

                codigo = int(codigo_item)
                data = int(data_item)

                self.dados["Códigos"].append(codigo)
                self.dados["Datas"].append(data)
                
                linhas_adicionadas += 1

                self.text_edit_2.clear()
                self.text_edit_3.clear()

            if linhas_adicionadas == self.num_linhas:
                break

        tabela = pd.DataFrame(self.dados)
        print(tabela)
```